How to Sample Multiple Completions (n) Directly from Claude API without a for loop?
I'm using the Anthropic Claude API and I'm trying to generate multiple completions (n completions) for a given prompt in a single API call. OpenAI's API provides an n parameter in their sampling settings to achieve this, but I can't find an equivalent option in the Claude API.
My Current Approach:
I'm currently using a retry mechanism to handle potential errors during API calls, which looks like this:
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_exponential

def before_sleep(retry_state):
    print(f"(Tenacity) Retry, error that caused it: {retry_state.outcome.exception()}")

def retry_error_callback(retry_state):
    exception = retry_state.outcome.exception()
    exception_str = str(exception)
    if "prompt is too long" in exception_str and "400" in exception_str:
        raise exception
    return 'No error that requires us to exit early.'

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(20), wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=2, max=256), 
       before_sleep=before_sleep, retry_error_callback=retry_error_callback)
def call_to_anthropic_client_api_with_retry(gen: AnthropicGenerator, prompt: str) -> dict:
    response = gen.llm.messages.create(
        model=gen.model,
        max_tokens=gen.sampling_params.max_tokens,
        system=gen.system_prompt,
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": [{"type": "text", "text": prompt}]}
        ],
        temperature=gen.sampling_params.temperature,
        top_p=gen.sampling_params.top_p,
        n=gen.sampling_params.n,  # Intended to generate multiple completions
        stop_sequences=gen.sampling_params.stop[:3],
    )
    return response

Problem:
I can't find an n parameter in the Anthropic API documentation that allows generating multiple completions in one request.
Questions:

Does the Claude API support generating multiple completions (n completions) directly within a single API call?
If not, is there a recommended workaround or best practice to achieve this without resorting to looping multiple requests?

cross discord: https://discord.com/channels/1072196207201501266/1213976011998498816/threads/1273440866861846549
cross: https://dev.to/brando90/how-to-sample-multiple-completions-n-directly-from-claude-api-without-a-for-loop-2m1e

For now doing this:
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(20), wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=2, max=256), 
       before_sleep=before_sleep, retry_error_callback=retry_error_callback)
def call_to_anthropic_client_api_with_retry(gen: AnthropicGenerator, prompt: str) -> dict:
    # max_tokens=8192,  # max_tokens for Claude 3.5 https://docs.anthropic.com/en/docs/about-claude/models#model-comparison
    # client = anthropic.Anthropic(api_key=gen.api_key)
    # response = client.messages.create(
    # response_text: str = gen.llm.messages.create(
    #     model=gen.sampling_params.model,
    #     max_tokens=gen.sampling_params.max_tokens,
    #     # temperature=temperature,  # note the prompt generator doesn't give this as an input
    #     system=gen.sampling_params.system,
    #     messages=[
    #         {"role": "user", "content": [{"type": "text", "text": prompt}]}
    #     ],
    #     temperature=gen.sampling_params.temperature,
    #     top_p=gen.sampling_params.top_p,
    #     n=gen.sampling_params.n,
    #     stop=gen.sampling_params.stop[:3],
    # ).content[0].text
    if not hasattr(gen.sampling_params, 'n'):
        gen.sampling_params.n = 1
    content: list[dict] = [] 
    for _ in range(gen.sampling_params.n):
        response = gen.llm.messages.create(
            model=gen.model,
            max_tokens=gen.sampling_params.max_tokens,
            system=gen.system_prompt,
            messages=[
                {"role": "user", "content": [{"type": "text", "text": prompt}]}
            ],
            temperature=gen.sampling_params.temperature,
            top_p=gen.sampling_params.top_p,
            n=gen.sampling_params.n,
            stop_sequences=gen.sampling_params.stop[:3],
        )
        content.append(response)
    response = dict(content=content)
    # message example: https://docs.anthropic.com/en/api/messages-examples
    return response

